# Reading and Writing large files (>1Gb) using Java NIO suitable?

Tags: java, performance, nio, large-files, memory-efficient

i am trying to read and write a large file typically more than 1 Gb files in each transaction to another storage location. what is the most efficient in terms of performance and low memory (preventing any OOM situation) to transfer the file by writing it to another storage location?

i saw Java NIO is a more efficient way as compared to traditional Java IO but is it really suitable in my use case and will it be an overkill?

Comment: [`FileChannel#transferTo(long,long,WritableByteChannel)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo(long,long,java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel)) may fit your needs.

Comment: java.nio.files.File has a copy() method - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29

Answer (score -1):

I have tried copying large files of this size (1GB). The time taken depends more on the underlying hardware and network status than Java NIO itself. As a simple example that I tried just now, copying a file of 989M took the following average timings.

**Note:** There was not much difference when the file already existed and needed to be replaced.

1. From an SSD folder to an SSD folder: 4ms
2. From an SSD folder to an HDD (5400rpm) folder: ~7ms
3. From an HDD(5400rpm) folder to an SSD folder: 4ms
4. From an HDD(5400rpm)folder to an HDD (5400rpm) folder: ~7ms

I observed the following:

1. That reading is not causing much of a difference.
2. That replacing an existing file with new contents is not causing much difference.
3. That there is a difference in writing based on the hard disk.

When we run tests on network drives, I am sure there will be great variation due to network variables.

Comment: If I use mapped memory buffer for large files more than 1 gb, will it use too much memory?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't think I know what the term "mapped memory buffer" means. Can you please explain?

Comment: i am not good at explaining technically. This link explains the mapped memory buffer https://howtodoinjava.com/java7/nio/memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer/

Comment: @WillsSeet OK. I understand. I think the use case you have mentioned here (copying files) need not use ```FileChannel.map()``` (which is an implementation of memory-mapping). Memory mapping, though I have used it only sparingly, seems to be good for cases  where you have frequent, multiple reads or writes into large files. Eg, what **Apache Lucene**, the search engine, does. It manipulates and reads from various portions of an index file (or directory) many times over. I am not sure if it is needed for one-time copying. However, let us see if there are other comment on this.